# PHP execute curl Oauth

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I want to send the following header using curl:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",⤦
⤥oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature="xxx"' ⤦
⤥'https://external.ningapis.com/xn/rest/apiexample/1.0/Photo/recent⤦
⤥?xn_pretty=true&fields=image.url,title&count=2'
```

Above command is for command line usage. Anyone know how to execute this using PHP curl?

Comment: Are these your real keys, I wonder... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-H` from curl command-line is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` in PHP curl [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt).

This should be the most basic example for what you need:

```
$auth = 'Authorization: YOUR_KEYS';
$url  = 'https://external.ningapis.com/xn/rest/apiexample/1.0/Photo/recent?xn_pretty=true&fields=image.url,title&count=2';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```