# Execute PHP using Curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to exceute this using php curl

```
 [ ~ ] $ curl -u cbb8f088775cf209035729c0eb69b9f340a3b047:X https://subs.pinpayments.com/api/v4/meresheep/subscribers.xml
```

So far, I tried

```
    // Query the user to pin payments for the details...
 $curl_url = "https://subs.pinpayments.com/api/v4/rigid-test/subscribers/rigids-12345.xml";

 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: -u cbb8f088775cf209035729c0eb69b9f340a3b047'));
 // curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('cbb8f088775cf209035729c0eb69b9f340a3b047')
));

 //execute post
 echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo curl_error($ch);
 die('qqqqqqqqq');
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: it is easy to do negative, but at least someone shall take initiative to help

Comment: [**Here we go**](https://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Your question contains invalid example code (can not be executed) (also: dead code). Next to that you formulate your question much too broad. If you wonder how to pass username and password via curl, please see the PHP manual page for curl_set_opt - yes it's large, so those who can read have a better position. Alternatively, look up the terms of what you do and use the search function. You're hardly the first one who asks about this on this website. Good luck reading, searching and learning the terms.

Comment: similar questions have been already posted and obviously user will ask question where he/she is getting problems.

Comment: @hakre just go through stack overflow first and check to see, is this really first time u saw such question on site

Comment: @hakre see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848666/how-to-form-php-curl-request-for-the-following-command-line or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071420/php-execute-curl

Comment: Well, you obviously can't read. I first suggested you to look into the PHP manual: http://php.net/curl_setopt - `-u` on curl command-line is `CURLOPT_USERPWD` in PHP's `curl_setopt`. See as well: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BPHP%5D+CURLOPT_USERPWD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly the variable used was wrong.
Here is the code again.

```
 // Query the user to pin payments for the details...
 $curl_url = "https://subs.pinpayments.com/api/v4/rigid-test/subscribers/12345.xml";

 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"b59d75bbdead46741b3b6875fc4b50e698392d71:test4321"); 


 //execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

 echo curl_error($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
```